# How to set date entered manually in OwlDateTime in Angular 6

Tags: angular

I use owlDateTime as my datetimepicker. The date/time is set when selected from the calendar (after clicking 'Set'). However, it is not set when entered manually on the input field. How can the date be set then just by typing it on the input field and pressing enter or tab? Below is my code:

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="toDate">To Date Time<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
      <div class="input-group">
          <input [min]="min" [owlDateTime]="dt2" class="form-control" formControlName="toDate" id="toDate" placeholder="YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM" style="width: 12em;">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-light fa fa-calendar trigger" type="button" [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt2"></button>
          </div>
      </div>
      <owl-date-time #dt2></owl-date-time>  
    </div>
```